# Put Multiple Paragraphs on Screen in Android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am developing an android based mobile application. I want to put multiple paragraphs which user can see and can scroll up and down. I don't know how to add multiple paragraphs either via XML or through java code. I am working on Eclipse IDE for android development.
I'll be thankful if anybody shed some light on it.
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Option #1: Use a `WebView`.

Option #2: Use a `TextView`, perhaps inside a `ScrollView`, with your paragraphs being defined in HTML and converted to something a `TextView` can use by `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: Thanks @ CommonsWare! I am very new in android. will you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @user1476497: Only if you elaborate on what you do not understand.

Comment: if I use webview to display some of my paragraphs, how can i enter my text? i use android:text="paragraph1 \n paragraph2 \n paragraph3" but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1476497: Step #1: Learn HTML. Step #2: In Java, call `Html.fromHtml()`, passing your HTML as a parameter. Step #3: Take the results of `Html.fromHtml()` and pass that to `setText()`, called on your `TextView` from Java, rather than using `android:text`.